# Having issue accessing mysql server from other machine

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have installed mysql server and workbench on a machine that is running on Ubuntu Linux platform.I also have installed mysql server and workbench on my machine that is running with Windows 7 OS.Both the machine are connected to network.I want connect to the mysql server from my machine.i tried changing the bind address of mysql server according to the machine's ip, and gave that ip as host name while connecting through mysql workbench from my machine.But i am not able to connect successfully.Please Help

Answer (score 2):

Well, IMHO, the only problems that could be are ither:

1. Username does not have enough priveleges
2. Server does not accept connections
3. Firewall Blocking port

You should investigate each of these cases